# How to add Indicators in qlikView?

Tags: qlikview

I have two columns in a table One holds date while other Sales Data .Comparing data of previous day i need to show indicators .If sales increases then green arrow else red arrow

Comment: use the 'image' in the representation tab: http://postimg.org/image/it4k940xj/

and then in the expression definition: http://postimg.org/image/mps3yg4sl/

if you click on the advanced button you will see all images available

Answer (score 3):

Add a column where you calculate whether the value increased or decreased (set expressions will be useful for this), and then on the `Expression` tab change the `Representation` to the kind of chart that suits you.